# Importing HTML to html page

Tags: html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to import the html from an externally created html file.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I have created a quiz centre for work.  Basically on each page there are up to 10 different teams represented, and they can choose to include upto  50 quizzes in their team section.  The quizzes are independent of the teams so they can be used more than one on the page.  The quiz opens via an iframe in a modal - see below.

```
<h4>General Quizzes</h4>
                <ul>
                   <li>
                       <p><i class="icon-file"></i>
                             <a data-toggle="modal" href="#GeneralQuiz">General MF Quiz</a></p>

                                    <div class="modal hide fade myModal_slick" id="GeneralQuiz" tabindex="-1">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                   <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%"  src="General_quiz.html" scrolling="no"> </iframe>                                        </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                           <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                  </li>
```

Since I am reusing the quizzes or modals in different team sections on the same page I trying to save some code and try to import the modals from an external HTML file.

Essentiall I want this part of the code on an external html file:

```
<div class="modal hide fade myModal_slick" id="GeneralQuiz" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-header">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%"  src="General_quiz.html" scrolling="no"> </iframe>                                        
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Then have it called only by the data toggle:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#GeneralQuiz">General Quiz</a>
```

My work uses a Weblogic server so it does not support PHP, only Java, so I cannot seem to find a solution that will make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jsp include:

```
 <jsp:include page="General_quiz.html"/>
```

Obviously this requires that your main file be a jsp file not just a regular html file.

Comment: They tagged the question with jsp, so that's a safe assumption